# Specify k3s version in rancher local cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

In the [release page](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/releases/tag/v2.6.9) there is information about supported Kubernetes versions and the **default is v1.24.4**.
I use this command to run single node docker setup:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped \
-p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
--privileged \
rancher/rancher:v2.6.9
```

I need local cluster to be at Kubernetes version **v1.21.14** but I don't know how to specify this parameter? Is it even possible?